# apiary api movie db angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to have an a tag on posters to link to movie details based on movie ID, I've been reading their docs but I can't seems to make the api configuration to work. I keep getting 404 in the console log.

this is how I'm calling the api, this is to build image urls. Can anyone point out how to do this bit correctly.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.core')
    .factory('posterService', posterService)

  posterService.$inject = ['$q', '$http'];

  function posterService($q, $http) {

    var service = {
      getPoster: _getPoster,
    };

    return service;

    function _getPoster(id) {
      var params = {
              id: id,
              key: 'xxx'
          }

      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + id + '/images/api_key='+key,
      });
    }

  }

})();
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of a movie `id`?  Trying to mess around with the API to double-check that it works and I need one to test the endpoint you're looking at...

Comment: ID: 206647 in the api that's "Spectre" movie ID I keep getting 404, but just outputting the movies is fine using https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=xxx'

Comment: I'm 90% sure the issue is the endpoint you're using.  If I'm reading your code properly, the above will query for `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/id/images?api_key=xxx&id=206647` when the URL should actually be `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/206647/images?api_key=xxx`.  I would replace the URL line with `url:'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + id + '/images/api_key=' + yourKey`

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me why the key is undefined when I specified it. So I tried hardcoding the key instead putting it in a  variable.It's giving me 401.

Comment: I do not know, not all that knowlegable about the specifics of Angular factories / services.  I believe @Dontfeedthecode may have an answer that works, however.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica Yeah its not undefined anymore but its giving me 401 Unauthorized idk whether its the API or something in my code.

Comment: That would suggest there's something wrong with your API key.  I'd log what URL you are attempting to load, then trying to load it using your browser.  When I visited the URL with a valid API key, I got a list of pictures from the API.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing through the API key as part of your route, pass it through as a query string. Your ID and key are also in a params object, so you need to use params.id and params.key.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app.core')
    .factory('posterService', posterService)

  posterService.$inject = ['$q', '$http'];

  function posterService($q, $http) {

    var service = {
      getPoster: _getPoster,
    };

    return service;

    function _getPoster(id) {
      var params = {
              id: id,
              key: 'xxx'
          }

      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + params.id + '/images?api_key=' + params.key,
      });
    }

  }

})();
```

Comment: Hi, just did that before I read this message but its still giving me a 401 Unauthorized.